# force a frame to open new window in the top frame

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
<html>
......
   <iframe name="first">
       <html>
         ......
                <iframe name="second"></iframe>
                <iframe name="third"></iframe>
         ......
       </html>
   </iframe>
......

</html>
```

I want the third or second iframe to open the link which is clicked, open in the first frame. Target attribute not work.

It is possible ? if yes, then how to do it ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean here? (ie. specify "when page is opened from `x`, load in frame `y`" for each of your frames)

Comment: @LukeWillis I want the third or second iframe to open the link which is clicked, open in the first frame. Target attribute not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var WindowSrc = $("#second").attr("src");
window.open(WindowSrc);
```

**Note:** You will need to ensure that pop ups are allowed if you wish to open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can control where an iframe opens up with the target attribute on the `<a>` tag:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

> **_blank:** Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
>
> **_self:** Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
>
> **_parent:** Opens the linked document in the parent frame
>
> **_top:** Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
>
> **framename:** Opens the linked document in a named frame

Comment: Do you have a Fiddle or URL you can post?